# Homestead does not update code

Tags: javascript, laravel, homestead

I am running laravel with homestead. I am currently working just locally on my mac and everything worked well so far, until I found out, that the code I am working on is not refreshed when changes are made.

e.g:

I have updated my VueJS code and I am running gulp afterwards. When refreshing the website, I still have the old code in place. The VM is running properly, the url is set in the hosts file but the code I am changing in my javascript does not get updated, whereas the code in my HTML does get updated properly.

I just noticed, when I call "local.medifaktor" as mentioned in my host file, I see the old code. When I call 192.168.10.10, I am using the current one! Why is the code not updated when I the URL mentioned in the hosts file?

The gulp file I am using for the javascript is this:

```
mix.scripts([
        'resources/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js',
        'resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js',
        'resources/assets/vendor/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js',
        'resources/assets/vendor/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
        'resources/assets/vendor/pace/pace.min.js',
        'resources/assets/js/app.js',
        'resources/assets/js/main.js'
    ], 'public/js/app.js', './')
```

Here I added main.js as new file to be merged into app.js.

Then I included app.js in my HTML code:

```
...
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you update the version number for your JS? Maybe clear browser cache?

Comment: Just noticed, when I call local.medifaktor (mentioned in my hosts file) I see old code, when I use 192.168.10.10 I have the recent one. Why is this not updated?

Comment: Usually when it comes to JS/CSS, the browser attempts to cache the files. It updates based on version. Try `src="js/app.js?v=1"`, and whenever you update the JS files, change the `v` value.